# Homebrew error when attempting to execute ocamlc

Tags: macos, ocaml, homebrew

What is going on if I get the following message after installing homebrew and OCaml?  This is with Homebrew 0.9.5, with OCaml (objective-caml: stable 4.02.1 (bottled), HEAD) on OS X 10.9.5.

-bash: /usr/local/bin/ocaml: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/bin/ocamlrun: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I had failed to correct some errors found by `brew doctor` before I installed OCaml, specifically errors with user ownership in /usr/local/bin.  After correcting the brew doctor errors, I executed `brew link` and everything seemed to be okay.  However, I kept getting those bad interpreter errors.  After a `brew uninstall ocaml` and a `brew install ocaml`, the bad interpreter error went away and OCaml behaved the way I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should try OPAM (http://opam.ocaml.org). It can not only install the compiler (apart from libraries), it also allows you to keep multiple versions of the compiler on the same machine and switch between them.